# Show thumbnail of an OPC file in Windows Explorer

Tags: thumbnails, open-packaging-convention

I have an [OPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions)-file. It works fine. Now I'm trying to add thumbnail, so when this file is shown in Windows Explorer or, for example, as attachment in browser, my thumbnail is displayed.

I tried to add

```
<Relationship Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/thumbnail" Target="/thumbnail.png" Id="RTN1" />
```

to .rels file. I tried to add jpeg instead of png. I tried 32x32 and 64x64 sizes.

[Content_Types].xml:

```
<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png" />
```

or `<Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg" />`

Structure of my file:

- _rels

  - .rels
- thumbnail.png
- other files
- [Content_Types].xml

A markup example of working OPC-file with thumbnail and it's structure will me much appreciated.

EDIT 2:

I've managed to show thumbnail when extension of a file is 'xps'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to do with OPC format. Windows have it's own way to draw icon for each file extension. To have a specific icon drawn for a specific file extension you need to create a dll, which implements IThumbnailProvider interface and register it. More info [here](http://www.codemonkeycodes.com/2010/01/11/ithumbnailprovider-re-visited/).

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the xps-IThumbnailProvider for zip-files, no need to write your own one !!!**

Add the Thumbnail to your zip-file:

*Files must not have a BOM !!!*

*Try until your file displays the thumbnail if you rename it to .xps*

```
Public WriteOnly Property Thumbnail As Image
        Set(value As Image)
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim relsdir = Me.ZipArchivWriter.CreateEntry("_rels/", CompressionLevel.NoCompression)
                Using rels = Me.ZipArchivWriter.CreateEntry("_rels/.rels", CompressionLevel.Fastest).Open
                    Using w As New StreamWriter(rels, FXENCODING)
                        w.WriteLine(XMLSTART)
                        w.WriteLine("<Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"">")
                        w.WriteLine("<Relationship Target=""thumbnail.png"" Id=""R1"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/thumbnail"" />")
                        w.WriteLine("</Relationships>")
                    End Using
                End Using
                Using ct = Me.ZipArchivWriter.CreateEntry("[Content_Types].xml", CompressionLevel.Fastest).Open
                    Using w As New StreamWriter(ct, FXENCODING)
                        w.WriteLine(XMLSTART)
                        w.WriteLine("<Types xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"">")
                        w.WriteLine("<Default Extension=""rels"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"" />")
                        w.WriteLine("<Default Extension=""PNG"" ContentType=""image/png"" />")
                        w.WriteLine("</Types>")
                    End Using
                End Using
                Using tn = Me.ZipArchivWriter.CreateEntry(FXTHUMBNAIL, CompressionLevel.NoCompression).Open
                    value.Save(tn, ImageFormat.Png)
                End Using
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

**And then add your file-extension to the registry (ClassesRoot or CurrentUser):**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.frax\shellex\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{44121072-A222-48f2-A58A-6D9AD51EBBE9}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.frax\shellex\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}]
@="{44121072-A222-48f2-A58A-6D9AD51EBBE9}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.frax\shellex\PropertyHandler]
@="{45670FA8-ED97-4F44-BC93-305082590BFB}"
```

That's all...